# On changing scep identity certificate's signing algorithm

Tags: ios, certificate, enterprise, mdm, scep

We are using scep for distributing device identity certificate.
And we are now planning to use SHA-2 family signing to replace SHA-1 which we are currently using for the certificate.

Now the question is that there are already many devices installed the SHA-1 certificate.

I would like to know that how will the existing certificate be effected?
Will users need to re-enroll their device again?
Or can we issue a update command(or something like that) and automatically replace the existing identity certificate?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to re-enroll all the devices that are using the old certificate.

Recently, I renewed signing certificate for MDM enrollment profile for which I had to re-enroll the devices so that they use the profile with new signing certificate.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Can you elaborate more about the re-enroll process?

Comment: @Bin0li if signing certificate is renewed then the only issue is cosmetic in that the profile is listed as unsigned. Further, you can just make a change to any of your settings and that will repush new corresponding profiles to devices without re-enrollment. Depending on the platform, even MDM profile can be replaced that way.